# Moving from JSP to ASP.Net, How to manipulate page.aspx using the database?

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, jsp, jakarta-ee

When I used to work on JSP pages, I used to do something like this:

```
<% rset = stmt.execute ("select * from users");
   while(rset.next()) {    %>
   <div> <%=rset.getString(1)%> </div>
<% } %>
```

I used to manipulate how a Page would look like depending on the database results.

Now I'm working on ASP.Net, using visual studio and sqlserver, and I'm still a newbie, how can I do the same thing in ASP?

Comment: This depends on how are you writing your code, if you are using MVC with Razor or just simple Web Forms. With Razor you will have some sort of similar way to render the page as the code you have posted, but you will have to add the MVC design pattern to your application and if you are not familiar with design patterns probably it will  be better if you use Web Forms, in that case I suggest you to read some sort of tutorial on it. There are some good ones if you google ASP.NET tutorials. For example you can start reading [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're dealing with the webforms!
the very basic way is to place "Literals" instead of your JSP markup, and to set the values for those literals in the code behind in page_load or postback.